# mysql user ok, but fails when using laravel db:seed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
mysql user OK, fails in Laravel, db:seed
kriptor@LAPTOP-M7QO17H9:/mnt/c/Users/wealt$ mysql -ukriptor3 -psuper250
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 11
Server version: 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Now, when trying db:seed...

```
 php artisan db:seed
Seeding: UserSeeder

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'kriptor3'@'localhost' to database 'listjoe' (SQL: select * from `users`)

  at /home/kriptor/projects/listjoe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\{closure}()
      [internal]:0

  2   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'kriptor3'@'localhost' to database 'listjoe'")
      /home/kriptor/projects/listjoe/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDO/Exception.php:18

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

My .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=listjoe
DB_USERNAME=kriptor3
DB_PASSWORD=super250
```

Pretty confusing, hard to search for, I haven't found any examples for hours now. Any help is greatly appreciated.  SO is telling me to write more so...  I created the user in mysql using create user identified by, etc, then granted all privileges, and flush privileges. I think  all this is self explanatory, mysql user *should* be working in laravel. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you also make sure that you can `use` the database from the CLI? Once logged in try `use listjoe`

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes, I can use listjoe.

Comment: Don't put your credentials here!!

Comment: Thanks Daan.  well it's just localhost... or is that still stupid of me. I kind of needed to include it in order to explain the question?

Comment: please double check your .env  .

Comment: I have triple and quadruple checked it Shifat.  I created 3 users the same way, and tried all of them, of course they all failed.  That's what is  so frustrating about this. I'm thinking it has something to do with caching?  And I did do php artisan optimize:clear. Rebooted and did it again, still not working.  This is in wsl.  mysql service is up.  What else, I can't think of any other reason..

Comment: when I created the uesrs, I used sudo mysql -u root.  maybe the sudo ?  I'll try creating a user without it.  getting desperate here.  By the way,using root in laravel still  doesn't work. I tried php artisan migrate just to make sure, still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally just rm -rf and git clone it back in and now it's fine. Thanks for your help.